# Could not find method content() for arguments - Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to run the Signal app from Android studio, but I have the following error :

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Signal'.
> Could not find method content() for arguments [build_ln9dya767x5ojwb6lu9wg470$_run_closure1$_closure2$_closure4$_closure5@1a6eaf53] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.
```

The concerned line is **content** and is found in the build.gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter {
            content {
                includeVersion 'org.jetbrains.trove4j', 'trove4j', '20160824'
                includeGroupByRegex "com\\.archinamon.*"
            }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you configure Android Studio to use the Gradle Wrapper or are you using a local version of Gradle? The method [`content`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/repositories/ArtifactRepository.html#content-org.gradle.api.Action-) was added in version 5.1 of Gradle, so you will need at least this version to solve your problem. If you don't want to use the wrapper (which you should), you should use version 6.5 of Gradle, since its the version currently used by the Signal app.