# How to resolve "Run gradlew" error when building apk for react-native expo project

Tags: react-native, gradle, expo, apk, eas

I have a react-native expo project that I am trying to build an apk from using aes. I am using Visual Studio Code. When I run `eas build -p android --profile preview` it starts the build but it later fails at **Run gradlew** with this error:

> Could not find method content() for arguments [init_av9l7xi6zgcximh78939mktrf$_run_closure1$_closure3$_closure6$_closure7@684e7354] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.

The full error log:

```
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
Unzipping /home/expo/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.10.1-all/455itskqi2qtf0v2sja68alqd/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip to /home/expo/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.10.1-all/455itskqi2qtf0v2sja68alqd
Set executable permissions for: /home/expo/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.10.1-all/455itskqi2qtf0v2sja68alqd/gradle-4.10.1/bin/gradle
Welcome to Gradle 4.10.1!
Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Incremental Java compilation by default
 - Periodic Gradle caches cleanup
 - Gradle Kotlin DSL 1.0-RC6
 - Nested included builds
 - SNAPSHOT plugin versions in the `plugins {}` block
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/release-notes.html
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing
cache fileHashes.bin (/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/.gradle/4.10.1/fileHashes/fileHashes.bin) is corrupt. Discarding.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Initialization script '/home/expo/.gradle/init.gradle' line: 34
* What went wrong:
Could not find method content() for arguments [init_av9l7xi6zgcximh78939mktrf$_run_closure1$_closure3$_closure6$_closure7@684e7354] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 13s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

Various solutions I have researched suggest changing the gradle version in the gradle-wrapper.properties file located in the android folder: `yourappName\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties`
However - my project does not have an android folder.

I have tried running `gradle build --warning-mode` all but it says my project directory "does not contain a Gradle build."

Any ideas as to how I should go about resolving this? I am not familiar with gradle at all.

Comment: Gradle 4 is very very old. Make sure you use matching Java version (max Java 8) and set JAVA_HOME variable pointing to the Java 8 JDK.

Comment: @Robert I downloaded and installed Java 8 JDK and pointed the JAVA_HOME variable to it. I tried to run the apk build again but it failed again with the same error.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/65444056/150978. May be this error is related to the old artifact repository which was downloaded by Android SDK. Without knowing the gradle config file content it is difficult to guess what is going wrong.